# Call pdftk from vba using powershell

Tags: vba

I need to extract pages from a pdf file. I am using pdftk. I get to the point where I generate the command, and have been trying lots of tweaking but I keep getting errors that seem to stem from spaces in file paths. I know how to quote file paths so I am not sure why I cant get this. The path to pdftx comes under c:\program files (x86). It doesnt seem to like this path maybe because of the parentheses in the name, I'm not certain. After generating the code, I have pasted it directly into powershell and it works. It just doesnt when I call it from vba.

```
Pth1 = "c:\working\access\az\maricopa\Weekly Bookings Report.pdf"  
Pth2 = "c:\working\access\az\maricopa\Weekly Bookings Report Split 1-5.pdf"  
cmd = "powershell -noexit pdftk """ & Pth1 & """ cat 1-5 output """ & Pth2 & """"

Shell cmd,vbMaximizedFocus
```

I have also tried using script blocks {}, in which I first changed directory to the path of pdftk executable, but that does no good either. Can somebody here tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks a lot